# Styled-component is not getting apply to the component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Here is my Component, its not applying the style ie. background in my case to the component.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'

const TappableButton = (props) => {
  return(
  <div>
    <Button>{props.title}</Button>
  </div>)
}

const Button = styled.button`
  background: "red";
`;

export default TappableButton;
```

Comment: where did you applied that style?

Comment: I am using styled-component

Comment: @Justcode actually i got my mistake just now.. will add the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.. the issue is with the quotes, it works without quotes just updated "red" to red.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const Button = styled.button`
  background: "red";
`;
```

to

```
const Button = styled.button`
  background: red;
`;
```

You do not need quotes around that text.
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3mzbqe)